# how can i update balance after doing withdrawal and deposits(withdraw,deposit,balance inquiry) java

Tags: java, bank

I have a homework in java. I am tasked to build a bank that can withdraw, deposit and inquire balance. My problem is that I couldn't get to update my balance after deposits and withdrawals... I've tried everything I could do but still cant get the logic. Can someone help add to my program... thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bankJava 
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    double balance;
    double amount;

    public void withdraw() 
    {

        System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();

        balance = balance - amount;


    }

    public void deposit()
    {

        System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        balance = balance + amount;

    }

    public void accBalance()
    {


    }



}
```

---------------------------------MAIN--------------------------------

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bankJavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int action;

        bankJava wdraw = new bankJava();
        bankJava dposit = new bankJava();
        bankJava balanceInquiry = new bankJava();
        bankJava amount = new bankJava();

        do{

        System.out.println("Choose Action: ");
        System.out.println("(1) Withdraw");
        System.out.println("(2) Deposit");
        System.out.println("(3) Balance Inquiry");
        System.out.println("(4) Exit");
        action = input.nextInt();


        switch(action){



        //---------WITHDRAW------------//
        case 1 :

            System.out.println("******Withdraw******");
            wdraw.withdraw();
            System.out.println("***************************");


            break;

        //---------DEPOSIT------------//
        case 2 :

            System.out.println("******Deposit******");
            dposit.deposit();
            System.out.println("***************************");
            break;

        //-----------Balance Inquiry-------//
        case 3 :

            System.out.println("******Balance Inquiry******");
            balanceInquiry.accBalance();
            System.out.println("***************************");

            break;

        case 4 :

            System.out.println("Thank you for choosing our bank!");
            break;

        default :

            System.out.println("Invalid action.");
            break;

        } 
        }while(action != 4);

    }


}
```

Comment: I tried setting balance to 0 and as I deposit and check balance, it is still 0. I have no idea what code to add to update balance after doing some actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are instatiating 4 different JavaBank? Doing this for each operation you will execute each method in a different object. If I understand well your question I think you could resolve your problem easily working in the same object.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bankJavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int action;

        bankJava myJavaBank = new bankJava(); //creating the bank


        do{

        System.out.println("Choose Action: ");
        System.out.println("(1) Withdraw");
        System.out.println("(2) Deposit");
        System.out.println("(3) Balance Inquiry");
        System.out.println("(4) Exit");
        action = input.nextInt();


        switch(action){



        //---------WITHDRAW------------//
        case 1 :

            System.out.println("******Withdraw******");
            myJavaBank.withdraw(); //withdrawing from it
            System.out.println("***************************");


            break;

        //---------DEPOSIT------------//
        case 2 :

            System.out.println("******Deposit******");
            myJavaBank.deposit(); //deposit from it
            System.out.println("***************************");
            break;

        //-----------Balance Inquiry-------//
        case 3 :

            System.out.println("******Balance Inquiry******");
            myJavaBank.accBalance();
            //You don't post this method but I suppose it will refer to the same bank
            System.out.println("***************************");

            break;

        case 4 :

            System.out.println("Thank you for choosing our bank!");
            break;

        default :

            System.out.println("Invalid action.");
            break;

        } 
        }while(action != 4);

    }


}
```

Now should work. With your code you had 4 different bank, one only for deposit, one only for withdraw and so on. So one bank will continue to increase money, and one continue to decrease in negative.

Morover the *amount* parameter should not be a JavaBank parameter, bur a local variable inside each method so that it does not define a Bank.

Something like

```
public class bankJava 
{

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


double balance;

public void withdraw() 
{

    System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
    double amount = input.nextInt();

    balance = balance - amount;


}

public void deposit()
{

    System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
    double amount = input.nextInt();
    balance = balance + amount;

}
```

I also suggest to change the `input.nextInt()` with `input.nextDouble()` so that you create the *amount* as a double.

If you don't see the Balance Inquiry is because obviously you have the accBalance() method blank. Edit it like this:

```
public void accBalance(){
System.out.println("Your balance is: "+this.balance);
}
```

Comment: Your code works but the Balance Inquiry method must be shown. For example, Im going to deposit 300 and then withdraw 100 then as I choose Balance Inquiry, there is an output saying "Your current balance is 200".

Comment: This because your _accInquiry_ method is blank. Insert inside _accInquiry_ (in the javaBank class) a simple `System.out.println("Your current balance is "+this.balance);`

Comment: Oh yea got it! Thank you so much for your time. Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited the main answer so that you could read easily. Your welcome bro, glad to have helped you! :)

Comment: Thanks sir! +reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankJava {

    double balance = 0;
    double amount;

    public void withdraw(int amount) {

        balance = balance - amount;

    }

    public void deposit(int amount) {

        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public double showBalance() {
        return balance;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankJava bank = new BankJava();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int action;
        int amount;
         do{

                System.out.println("Choose Action: ");
                System.out.println("(1) Withdraw");
                System.out.println("(2) Deposit");
                System.out.println("(3) Balance Inquiry");
                System.out.println("(4) Exit");
                action = input.nextInt();
                switch(action){
                //---------WITHDRAW------------//
                case 1 :

                    System.out.println("******Withdraw******");
                    System.out.println("enter amount:");
                    amount = input.nextInt();
                    bank.withdraw(amount);
                    System.out.println("***************************");
                    System.out.println("Your balance is now: " + bank.showBalance());
                    break;

                //---------DEPOSIT------------//
                case 2 :

                    System.out.println("******Deposit******");
                    System.out.println("enter amount:");
                    amount = input.nextInt();
                    bank.deposit(amount);
                    System.out.println("***************************");
                    System.out.println("Your balance is now: " + bank.showBalance());
                    break;

                //-----------Balance Inquiry-------//
                case 3 :

                    System.out.println("******Balance Inquiry******");
                    System.out.println("Your balance is: " + bank.showBalance());
                    System.out.println("***************************");

                    break;

                case 4 :

                    System.out.println("Thank you for choosing our bank!");
                    break;

                default :

                    System.out.println("Invalid action.");
                    break;

                } 
                }while(action != 4);

            }
    }
```

Try this code, compare with yours and figure out whats wrong, also you can ask me if you need more help

Comment: There is a problem on this statement " System.out.println("Your balance is now: " + bank.showBalance());" it says 'void' type not allowed here... and also, in Balance Inquiry method, as soon as i choose that action, it must have its own class to perform.

Comment: Did you copy my showBalance() method? make sure it is public double showBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

Comment: oh got it. I missed that part hehe. Now it works perfectly! Thank you so much sir for helping me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Inquiry method shows the actual balance? just use showBalance() method there then :) edited my answer so you just have to copy and paste it, and you are welcome mate, you can ask me anything about that

Comment: Yup. Now I have to organize and clean the code(your code technically). Thanks man! Appreciate alot!